# Powershell Buttons only works on Second "run and debug"

Tags: powershell

I have a weird bug on PowerShell, so basically every time I try to run my script, everything works except my buttons. To give a better understanding of my script, I'm just going to explain it on an exit button.

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.FormBorderStyle = 0
$main_form.Text ='**'
$main_form.Width = 1080
$main_form.Height = 720
$main_form.BackColor = "#101010"
$main_form.AutoSize = $true

$btnClose = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnClose.Name = "Close"
$btnClose.Text = "X"
$btnClose.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter" 
$btnClose.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 10, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$btnClose.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$btnClose.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
$btnClose.BackColor = '#101010'
$btnClose.foreColor = '#FFFFFF'
$btnClose.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$btnClose.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1020, 30)
$btnClose.Add_Click($btnClose_Close)
$main_form.Controls.Add($btnClose)

$btnClose_Close = {
  $main_form.Close()        
        }
$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

I think It's straight forward what the button is doing, it's just closing the form. Now the more accurate explanation: If I'm starting the code for the first time in Visual Studio Code or in Windows PowerShell ISE, the button won't work at first, after I close it and run it again it magically works. And the Problem is, it would be fine if the script works without any IDE, but because of this bug the button won't work when it's run as a "normal PowerShell script" (left click "run with PowerShell" on Windows).

Thanks in advance, and apology for my bad English.

My guess was it's a problem of the IDE (Visual Studio Code) but when I saw, that it won't work on Windows PowerShell ISE either, I searched on the internet, but it seems like no one has this problem.

Comment: Can you add enough of the initialisation code (e.g. how you create the form) to make your sample cut-and-pasteable as a stand-alone script to try to reproduce the issue locally (and please *test* that your sample actually reproduces the issue). There may be lines of code that affect the behaviour without you even realising and it’ll be impossible for us to guess those…

Comment: hi, i added the creation of the form and tested it, still has the same "bug"

Comment: I can't explain it, but if you add your scriptlbock *inline* in the event handler it seems to work fine: ```$btnClose.Add_Click( { $main_form.Close() } )```. Knowing how fussy WinForms is with the UI thread, it's probably related to that, but I don't know enough about the nuances of it to really explain. Note that if you're *really* invested in declaring the scriptblock separately you can also *invoke* it inside a *nested* scriptblock from the event handler like this ```$btnClose.Add_Click( { $btnClose_Close.Invoke() } )```, and *that* seems to work as well...

Comment: The issue is that you are attempting to assign the script block to the click event before you have defined the script block. This is why running twice in a row works. On the second run (within an IDE or ISE) the script block variable already contains the value from the first run, which is then copied into the click event. Either move the declaration of the script block to be above the line that assigns the script block to the click event, or do it in line as @mclayton suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to assign a code block to your button click event before you define the code block.

Simply move your click event code block to a position above where you assign the click event. For example:

```
$btnClose_Close = {
  $main_form.Close()        
        }
$btnClose.Add_Click($btnClose_Close)
$main_form.Controls.Add($btnClose)
```

Of course, you could just as easily add the code inline like this:

```
$btnClose.Add_Click({$main_form.Close()})
$main_form.Controls.Add($btnClose)
```

In case you were wondering why the original code was working on the second run when executed from a development environment , here is the explanation:
When your code executes the first time it assigns the empty variable `$btnClose_Close` to the click event of your button. After that, it sets the desired value of `$btnClose_Close`. At that point the button will not work on the form. Then when you rerun the script, the variable `$btnClose_Close` still holds its value from the previous run. So now when you assign that variable to the click event, the script block gets added.